# Too slow when getting current style on Chrome using javascript

Tags: performance, google-chrome, computed-style

I am stuck with a stupid problem. Below is my code to get computed style of a dom. It run well on FireFox and even IE (surprised)! but too slow on chrome v17 (20x time slower). How to avoid the problem?

```
getCurrentStyle = function(el)
{
    if (el.currentStyle)
        return el.currentStyle;
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It's probably more to do with how often you're calling the function than the function itself.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my post: page run well on FF, not Chrome. The function was called very often: about 6000 times on start-up :(. It took 2 secs on FF but 30-40 secs on Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Chrome bug. So that we avoid to use this function:

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null)
```